# cant write to ID classes in a specific context

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

im trying to make a script that makes a mix node and assigns a driver to the factor. so far i can only create the driver before receiving this error that keeps the script from actually configuring the driver

[image]

im still able to get the driver created with this but all the other parts of the driver are default.

with my very limited experience with python, i suspect its because of the if statement that the driver code is in.

[image]

again, im not 100% sure the issue is in here. so just in case, this is the whole script

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.types import Operator

bpy.data.materials.new("Property Dump")
bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].use_nodes=True
##### VARIABLES ##############################################
built=False
dump="Property Dump"
dl=bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes
##### FUNCTIONS ##############################################
def build(): 
    
    
    prin=bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF']
    outputnode=bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes['Material Output']
    bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes.remove(prin)
    bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes.remove(outputnode)
    test=dl.new(type="ShaderNodeMix")
    test.location=(100, 100)

    
    def draw (self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col2 = layout.column()
        row = col.row()
        
#####
def main():
    global built
    built = True
#####
def fixDrivers():
    fix=bpy
#####  
##### OPERATORS ##############################################
class op(Operator):
    bl_label="ok"
    bl_idname="create.operator"
    def execute(self, context):
        built=True
        main()
        build()
        self.report({"INFO"},
            f"Compiled! Happy Editing!")
        return {'FINISHED'}
#####
class op2(Operator):
    bl_label="ok2"
    bl_idname="create.operator2"
    def execute(self, context):
        fixDrivers()
        self.report({"INFO"},
            f"Ok the drivers should be fine now")
        return {'FINISHED'}

##### PANELS ##############################################
class Create(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Main"
    bl_category = 'Create Addon'
    def draw (self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col2 = layout.column()
        row = col.row()
        if not built:
            col.operator(op.bl_idname, text="Build Addon!", icon='MODIFIER')
        else:
            col.label(text="u can close this now")
#####
class octo1panel(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Info"
    bl_category = 'Create Addon'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    def draw (self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col2 = layout.column()
        row = col.row()
        if built:
            col.operator(op2.bl_idname, text="Fix Drivers", icon='MODIFIER')
            bool=dl["Mix"].inputs[0]
            col.prop(bool, "default_value", text="Test Driver")
            col.label(text="Test Label")
            row = col.row()
            row.prop(context.scene, 'testbool', toggle=False, text='Test Bool')
            dtes= bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].driver_add("default_value")

            d = dtes.driver
            d.type= "SCRIPTED"
            d.expression = "my_var + 0.1"

            v = d.variables.new()
            v.name = "my_var"

            t = v.targets[0]
            t.id_type = 'OBJECT'
            t.id = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
            t.data_path = "scale[0]"
            

            
##### REGISTRATION ##############################################        
classes=[op, op2, Create, octo1panel,]
def register():
    
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)
    bpy.types.Scene.testbool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name='bool',
        default=False,    
)
def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
    del bpy.types.Scene.testbool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: From docs I see that FCurve.driver is *readonly*.  Now if I beat my head against the docs, I'll find a way to get an editable driver....

Comment: cant tell if this is sarcasm or not but im guessing its just not going to work for the time being

Comment: I'm seriously trying to be helpful, but don't know the answer yet.  If you read page https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurve.html and look at "driver" you'll see ```Type  Driver, (readonly)```.  *readonly* means a readonly variable that is copy of information that is not editable/writable/modifiable in that context.   There is probably another way access the changeable data through animation_data or some other means.  I just don't know the answer myself.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I will look into that

Comment: It is not possible to modify blender data in a `draw` method. You need to make your logic happen elsewhere